# How to stop animation transitions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, transition

Today, I learned how to add keyframes, however, When haveing 2 keyframes with different scales, instead of just going from one scale and just transforming into the other scale, it TRANSITIONS. How can I make it transform into the other scale, with not transitions?

[At 0:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYfwV.png), the scale for x and y is 0.25.

[At 0:03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O9g3.png), the scale for x and y is 0.3_.(Specifics do not matter.)

[At 0.05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8mpj.png), the scale for x and y is 0.45.

How can I make it so that when I go from 0.00 --> 0.499999, the scale stays at 0.25, but at 0.05, the scale becomes 0.45?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a unity forum [here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1116676/view.html). It says to select all wanted frames, change it to flat, and set both tangents to constant. That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat your first key frame at 0.04

Reference 
[image]

Although Scale values will lerp between 0:04 to 0:05 but it will be so fast that it will be unnoticeable.